# Performance in Glassfish CDI

Tags: java, glassfish, osgi, cdi

I want to develop CDI application in Glassfish 3.1.2 using OSGI and CDI. But I don't know what is the performance penalty in CDI applications. Can I use CDI in multithreaded applications? Can I pass large data structures using CDI?

Best Wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a performance penalty for using CDI, but in almost all cases where we deploy to glassfish it is negligible compared to everything else that is going on. Unless you specifically know/suspect that the CDI part of the code is where the application will spend most of its time I wouldn't have any second thoughts about using CDI. Our world is overcrowded with premature optimizations when we all know that optimization is done: When there is a problem, not when writing code. And done by profiling to find spots to optimize, and then optimizing thoose spots. The coding and maintainace time saved by using CDI should almost always outweigh the time it costs to revert to another technology if the need ever appear.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can I use miltithreads with CDI in order to increase the performance?

Comment: The exact answer is case by case. But yes the CDI architecture have no problems with multithreaded environments. But I have no answer for if multi-threading your application will improve the CDI speed for your application. (In most scenarios the multi-threading part is handled by the container, glassfish in this case. Depending on the application I suggest letting glassfish handle all multithreading, if it is a full JavaEE application it is strongly suggested.)

Comment: I think my main point is ... don't worry about the performance of CDI. For me to change that view, you'd need to specifiy what is so unique with your application(domain) that a lot of time is gonna be spend on CDI.